# Combining output parsers and chains in Langchain

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

I am not able to pass dictionary as an an input to simple sequential chain.  For Example, if I have a dictionary like

`output dict = {'location': 'Newyork', 'deadline': '2', 'stay': '7', 'budget': '10000'}`

And I want to write a SimpleSequentialChain like

```
from langchain.chains import SimpleSequentialChain
from langchain.prompts import HumanMessagePromptTemplate
llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.9,model=llm_model)

template_one = """You will be provided a dictionary like {output_dict} get the corresponding value of the keys named 'budget' and 'deadline' from dictionary.
                 return the result(only a whole number) divided by corresponding values of budget and deadline

                """
prompt_template_one = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(template=template_one)
chain_one = LLMChain(llm=llm,prompt=prompt_template_one)
template_two = """ get the result multiply the {value} by 3 and 

                return only whole number
                """

prompt_template_two = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(template=template_two)
chain_two = LLMChain(llm=llm,prompt=prompt_template_two)

final_chain = SimpleSequentialChain(input_variables= ["output_dict"],chains=[chain_one,chain_two],output_variables=["value","result"],verbose=True)

final_chain(output_dict)
final_chain = SimpleSequentialChain(chains=[chain_one], verbose=True)

result = final_chain.predict_and_parse(output_dict)
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

The expected flow and result is something like:

from chain one the result should be 5000 (budget/deadline)

chain 2 should get this input and multiply it by 5 --> 15000